# 'createsuperuser' command un known while trying to get started with Djangoappengine

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I am trying to get going with [Djangoappengine](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine). I followed the instructions, but when I get to this step:

manage.py createsuperuser

I get the following:

Unknown command: 'createsuperuser'

So I ran

manage.py help

And saw that 'createsuperuser' is not even in the list.
The list of subcommands listed by help:

```
  cleanup
  compilemessages
  createcachetable
  dbshell
  deploy
  diffsettings
  dumpdata
  flush
  inspectdb
  loaddata
  makemessages
  remote
  reset
  runfcgi
  runserver
  shell
  sql
  sqlall
  sqlclear
  sqlcustom
  sqlflush
  sqlindexes
  sqlinitialdata
  sqlreset
  sqlsequencereset
  startapp
  syncdb
  test
  testserver
  validate
```

I can't figure out what has gone wrong here, as I am a total newbe with this stuff. I don't even know exactly what 'createsuperuser' is suppose to do, other than obviously creating a super user of some sort. :)

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to activate django.contrib.auth in your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py.

Comment: Waldemar, it sounds so simple when you say it like that. ;) Thanx much, I'll try that. At least I got you to register on StackOverflow! ::)

Comment: OK, I did that and it worked. Thanx! Does it create that superuser in the data store? Before prompting for the account info though, I got this error: "dev_appserver.py:3617] Could not initialize ima
ges API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module. ImportError: No module". What am I doing wrong here? I got another error, that datastore_file_stub.py could not read from the datastore file, but that went away when I ran the command again, so I assume the file just didn't exist and then the command created the datastore the first time I ran it. Is that right? Thanx for any further help.

Comment: The first error happens because you haven't installed the PIL module. Look here for more details: http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

Answer (score 5):

I also had this problem, but django.contrib.auth was already in INSTALLED_APPS.  For me, it was that my environment vars hadn't been set in this tab of terminal (despite no error to that effect).  I figured this out by running manage.py syncdb, which gave me the appropriate error:

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
```

Once I set my environment vars, createsuperuser ran fine.